# Future method executing (success), but not working

Tags: apex, future, java, method, execute-anonymous

I bulk-updating phone numbers on objects, following method working on single or multiple numbers, but when I delete conditions in query for low amount of records, its exception CPU time exceeded. So I added @future annotation (with hope that it will work properly because method is running simultaneously hence shorter CPU time), its executing with success, but records are not updated. What are my options?

```
@Future(Callout=true)
    public static void updatePhoneNumbers(){
        List<Account> accList = [SELECT Phone FROM Account WHERE Phone != NULL] ;
        for (Account account : accList){
            if (account.Phone.startsWith('0')) {
                account.Phone = account.Phone.replaceFirst('0','+421');
            } else if (account.Phone.startsWith('421')) {
                account.Phone = '+'+account.Phone;
            }else {
                account.Phone = '+421'+account.Phone;
            }
        }
        update accList;
```

Executing it through Anonymous Apex.

Comment: What do logs say? Is the execution marked as success in Setup-> Apex Jobs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternate approach for better debugging : Use Queueable instead of future and put debug logs on your queried list to check if it is being retrieved as expected.

Take control of your asynchronous Apex processes by using the Queueable interface. This interface enables you to add jobs to the queue and monitor them. Using the interface is an enhanced way of running your asynchronous Apex code compared to using future methods.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm

Comment: Can you add why Queuable is better? Also, provide an illustration of what you mean. Link-only answers are actively discouraged here as SF changes link and your answered would become irrelevant.

Comment: not sure if this was a "link only" answer, ability to monitor asynchronous apex is a very vital reason for choosing queueable over future methods as I refer in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `@future` is triggered successfully, but the execution is actually happening in a different transaction so a separate debug log. There might be a hiccup happening there..

So if I'm not mistaken, you're putting +421 in front of all numbers that don't start with that yet. After your update, any number will start with +421.

So you could include that as an exclusion criteria in your SOQL query (`AND PHONE NOT LIKE '+421%'`). Then, since you're running it manually anyway, just run it a couple of times with '`LIMIT 10000`' added to the SOQL query (or whatever number is the max you can do without hitting CPU limit).